# Regular expression to extract errors in a maven build log

Tags: java, regex, bash, maven

I have a Java project being built using maven. I am about to start doing nightly's and I would like my nightly build server to extract the errors in a log file using bash. For this, I imagine I would use regular expression but I am no professional when it comes to regexp.

Here is a sample of the log file:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 24.085 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-08T14:14:07-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 39M/347M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project amb-collections: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /src/branches/dev/amb-collections/AbstractMultiMap.java:[1] Syntax error on token "badsyntax", delet$
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :amb-collections
```

My goal here is to extract the file in question, with the entire path and the error associated. If regex is not a solution or perhaps there is simply a better one, suggestions are very welcomed!

Line to extract: **[ERROR] /src/branches/dev/amb-collections/AbstractMultiMap.java:[1] Syntax error on token "badsyntax", delet$**

Expected output:
Path: **/src/branches/dev/amb-collections/AbstractMultiMap.java**
Line: **1**
Message: **Syntax error on token "badsyntax", delet$**

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @anubhava Updated the OP

Comment: Sorry my bad. Didn't read the question completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk command to parse your output:

```
awk -F '[][,:]+' 'index($0, "[ERROR] ") && index($3, " /") == 1 {
      printf "Path:%s\nLine: %s\nMessage:%s\n", $3, $4, $5}' file.log
```

**Output:**

```
Path: /src/branches/dev/amb-collections/AbstractMultiMap.java
Line: 1
Message: Syntax error on token "badsyntax"
```

Explanation:

This awk command used a regex for splitting fields of each line:

```
[][,:]+
```

Which means 1 or more of `]` or `[` or `,` or `:`

That gives us fields nicely broken up with above characters. `index` function performs non-regex search in the given string.

Comment: Worked like a charm... Thank you so much!

Comment: I would be nice if you could provide some information about your solution.

Comment: I've added some explanation in my answer.